# Unable to truncate lightning:formattedRichText text

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, lightning-design-system

I have a problem with a  lightning:formattedRichText element. Below my code :

```
                                <ul class="slds-list_horizontal slds-has-dividers_left">
                                    <li class="slds-item">
                                        <div class="slds-text-title slds-text-color_default slds-p-right_small" >
                                            <!--{!script.Accroche_Commerciale__c}-->
                                            <lightning:formattedRichText class='slds-truncate' style="font-size : 1.1em ;" value="{!script.Accroche_Commerciale__c}"/>

                                        </div>
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
```

And it displays like this :
[image: The rendering result of my code]

I have already tried some solution suggested in similar questions like putting the **script.Accroche_Commerciale__c** in a div but it doesn't work. Also, when I remove the **lightning:formattedRichText** it displays the result as an html code with **p** and **br** balises.

So what I need is to not exceed the size of card element in the right side and also limit the number of lines displayed to 5.

Any help will be so much appreciated.

Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

You probably solved this by now, but in case anyone else wonders, you should be able to limit the number of lines to 5 with a slds-line-clamp_medium class.
Check out the full doc here [SLDS Line Clamp](https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/utilities/line-clamp/)